# How to sort each row in pandas dataframe and get indices instead?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a pandas DataFrame containing probabilities. What I need is a new DataFrame where each row contains the indices of the sorted row. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.5,0.7,0.1],[0.1,0.7,0.5]])
df
     0    1    2
0  0.5  0.7  0.1
1  0.1  0.7  0.5

new_df = some sort operation on df
new_df
    0  1  2
0   1  0  2
1   2  0  1
```

I know how to do it the hard way, using multiple loops and such. I found references to sorting values but no "sorting" function that returned the indices. Anyone some suggestion?

Comment: use `.index` to get the indices for each column after sort (ensure NOT inplace), then build the required dataframe!

Comment: how do you have 2,1,0 in the second row? shouldnt it be 1,2,0?

Comment: @anky: He just has a typo in his definition of `df` (the output suggests `df[1][1]` was `0.5` instead of the `0.7` stated in the example).

I'd probably just do `df.transform(lambda s: np.argsort(-s.values), axis=1)`

Comment: @Anky, i see what you mean, typo indeed. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use numpy for that with argsort:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.5,0.7,0.1],[0.1,0.7,0.5]])
array = df.values.argsort(axis=1)[:,::-1]
new_df  = pd.DataFrame(array)
```

output `new_df`:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   0   2
1   1   2   0
```

Note:

as commented by @anky there is something that doesnt make sense in the ouput you show,, also i assumed you want descending order and thats why the `[:,::-1]` slice in the result/

**UPDATE**

as @anky suggested in comments here it is still using the same idea of argsort,
this is more strightforward solution then `df.values.argsort(axis=1)[:,::-1]`:

```
np.argsort(-df)
```